# home router + tp link access point + tp-link router

Tags: router

I'm in my beginning of the journey of studying to CCENT exam and I got myself confused regarding the home setup.

I was looking at the ip address of my home network where we have one black box (router) to which a fiber optic cable is connected to directly from the ISP and from that black box there's an RG-45 cable connected to a TP-LINK access point.

Now, we're using network 192.168.1.0/24 for all devices which is pretty much what I'm used to.

However, when I want to access the TP-LINK access point I've to change my PC ip address to static to network 192.168.0.0/24 so that I can access (192.168.0.254)

Now aren't those on different networks? how does it work, can anyone explain this to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, that's why you have to change your PC's IP address to something within the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet in order to access the AP's configuration pages. If you change the AP's IP address to something within the 192.168.1.0/24 subnet (e.g. 192.168.1.254), you wouldn't have to change your PC's IP address to get into the AP's configuration. Alternatively, you could also change your local network's subnet to 192.168.0.0/24 and keep the AP's IP address unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ip address is an ip in the range 192.168.1.1-254 , and you can speak directly to one machine that have a similar address (in the same subnet)
this is a logical network 
you cannot speak directly to the ap ip address (192.168.0.0/24) that is in another logical network,

but on the same media type , physical network,  you can have multiple logical network
that' s your case, the two logical network share the same physical network
if you use wireshark to see the ethernet traffic you can find the broadcast packet of either your two logical network